# Undefined Reference when using inline functions in C

Tags: c, function, inline, undefined-reference, inline-functions

This is straight from the GeeksForGeeks' tutorial on C page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interesting-facts-preprocessors-c/

```
#include <stdio.h>
inline int square(int x) { return x*x; }
int main()
{
int x = 36/square(6);
printf("%d", x);
return 0;
}
// Output: 1
```

I get the error:
/tmp/ccSHJFrH.o: In function `main':
a54a7786ee0a4f730407c05eb1147f5f.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to`square'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

For some reason this compiles when compiling with C++, but with C, I get the error message above. I am running this on the IDE on the GeeksForGeeks website.

https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/index.php

Comment: That code is undefined behaviour in ISO C. Remove `inline` to make it work

Comment: On the other hand, perfectly valid in contemporary C standards. Turn up the compiler flags.

Comment: @M.M I misread as "ansi C", apologies. What's wrong with `inline` in C then? It's been used since C99.

Comment: @DeiDei I've linked another question. Nothing's wrong with `inline` per se, just this code uses it incorrectly

Comment: Alternatively, add `static` to the function declaration to make it work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `inline` affects the linkage as described in the linked question

Comment: And note that although the `inline` specifier requests that calls to the so-marked function be as fast as possible, implementations are not required to honor such requests in any way, and those that do are not required to do so by actually inlining the called function body into its caller.